# Vue.js open link in new window

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have in Vue.js code

```
  <div class="footer-items">
  <span v-for="link in links" :key="link.name">
  <a :href="link.Link" class="tertiary--text footer-links">{{ link.name }}</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

The this gives me a footer with some links.  I would like to have some of these links open an external window or tab.

The array that it loads from is:

```
   data: () => ({
   links: [
  { name: "Home", Link: "/dashboard" }, // needs to open same page
  { name: "PubMed", Link: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed" } // needs new window
  ]
```

This works but it open in the same window, I've tried:

```
        { name: "PubMed", Link: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/,_blank" },  // error page

        { name: "PubMed", Link: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/','_blank" }, // open same page

        { name: "PubMed", Link: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/"','"_blank" },  // won't compile

        Link: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/ target=_blank"  // opens same window
```

Is it possible programmatically send it to the href. I can't change the href because not all pages need to open in a new window.

I changed the code to:

```
          <a :href="link.Link" target="link.place" class="tertiary--text 
           footer-links">{{ link.name }}</a>
```

and added to the array a location:

```
          { name: "Home", Link: "/dashboard", place: "_self" },
           {name: "PubMed", Link: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/",
           place: "_blank"
         },
```

And they all open in new windows. All help is appreciated.

Comment: you're missing the `:` in `:target="link.place"`

Comment: Like Daniel mentionned you forgot the `:`. Please consider adding `rel="noopener noreferrer"` for the links with `target="_blank"`. You can learn more about this: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Comment: Thank you to all-- you are great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dj2cv3qx/)):

```
// Script
links: [
    { name: "Home", href: "/dashboard", target: "_self" },
    { name: "Google", href: "https://www.google.com/", target: "_blank" },
]

// Template
<a
    v-for="link in links"
    :key="link.name"
    :href="link.href"
    :target="link.target"
    rel="noopener noreferrer">
    {{ link.name }}
</a>
```

Comment: Works great-- Thanks